# javascript reading csv file returning empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, csv

I am trying to use a function to read csv file and return it. but unfortunately i got an empty string

```
function getStations() {

    var final_results = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "CSV.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);

            //Set up the data arrays
            var stations_data = [];

            //var headings = lines[0].split(','); // Splice up the first row to get the headings
            for (var j = 1; j < lines.length; j++) {
                var values = lines[j].split(','); // Split up the comma seperated values
                // We read the key,1st, 2nd and 3rd rows 

                // tmp_data.push(parseFloat(values[0])); 
                //tmp_data.push(parseFloat(values[1]));
                //tmp_data.push(parseFloat(values[2]));
                //tmp_data.push(values[4]);
                stations_data.push(values[4]);
                final_results.push(values[4]);
            }

            console.log("inside:" + final_results.length)
        }
    });

    // Let's process the data from the data file
    console.log("outside: " + final_results.length);
}
```

the results is as following:
[console.log results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdXNP.png)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log('outside..` statement gets executed before the ajax has finished.
You will have to do some sort of callback for when the `final_results` is loaded.

```
function getStations(callback) {

    var final_results = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "CSV.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);

            //Set up the data arrays
            var stations_data = [];

            //var headings = lines[0].split(','); // Splice up the first row to get the headings
            for (var j = 1; j < lines.length; j++) {
                var values = lines[j].split(','); // Split up the comma seperated values
                // We read the key,1st, 2nd and 3rd rows 

                // tmp_data.push(parseFloat(values[0])); 
                //tmp_data.push(parseFloat(values[1]));
                //tmp_data.push(parseFloat(values[2]));
                //tmp_data.push(values[4]);
                stations_data.push(values[4]);
                final_results.push(values[4]);
            }

            callback(final_results)
        }
    });
}

getStations(function (final_results){
    console.log("outside: " + final_results.length);
})
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I made the changes: getstations.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Object.success (getstations.js:28)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)

Comment: you must replace `getStations()` with `getStations(function (final_results) ...)`